# Issue with linking in Fedora 32 bit OS

Tags: linux, fedora, 32bit

Can anyone help what is this error mean? I am new to Linux Environment

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../bin/linux.i486/libLogLibrary.a when searching for -lLogLibrary
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLogLibrary
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../bin/linux.i486/libXMLLibrary.a when searching for -lXMLLibrary
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXMLLibrary
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you linking a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit build host? Could be that ``-m32`` is missing from ``CFLAGS``.

Comment: Yes dear -phg..I am building source code on 32bit OS which is running on 64 bit host

Comment: In that case, please supply some more info about the build environment: What build system? C or C++? What was the last command that invoked the linker? (You may be able to re-run the latter directly with ``-verbose`` passed to GCC to get a list of libs in the path that it attempted to link against.)

Comment: Build environment - Fedora 32 bit OS on a 64 bit processor.Build system C++.Last command invoked linker was "make -C ../LogLibrary"

Comment: For C++ try ``export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -m32"`` before building. Is there some build system like cmake, meson, or autotools that you use to setup the build?